# Can't include LWJGL using Maven in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, maven, lwjgl

I'm trying to build my project with LWJGL library included, using Maven and VSC, but I can't understand how is it working.

I was looking into http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Maven.html, but  console is saying me, that it doesn't know what methods, which I am using, are...

I'm trying to build example from https://www.lwjgl.org/guide. There is repo for ant build sistem, but it is necessary for me to use Maven. Please, help me to adapt it.

**UPD**

After I copypasted pom.xml from link given in post, I got following errors:

```
> Executing task: mvn -B verify <

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for myProject:myGame:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 62, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< myProject:myGame >--------------------------
[INFO] Building myGame 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from slick: http://slick.cokeandcode.com/mavenrepo/slick/slick/274/slick-274.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.873 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-09T03:13:22+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myGame: Could not resolve dependencies for project myProject:myGame:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at slick:slick:jar:274: Failed to read artifact descriptor for slick:slick:jar:274: Could not transfer artifact slick:slick:pom:274 from/to slick (http://slick.cokeandcode.com/mavenrepo): slick.cokeandcode.com: Unknown host slick.cokeandcode.com -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

And  after I removed every ssection. which was containing 'Slick' (Since it isn't used in test example from lwjgl.org/guide), Maven built project successfully. But I still can't run project. I type `java *myclass*` and I get

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problems:
>         Version cannot be resolved
>         The method glfwFreeCallbacks(long) is undefined for the type Main
>         The method glfwDestroyWindow(long) is undefined for the type Main
>         The method glfwTerminate() is undefined for the type Main
>         The method glfwSetErrorCallback(null) is undefined for the type Main
> 
>         at game.Main.run(Main.java:36)
>         at game.Main.main(Main.java:128)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please include the error in your description and the exact issues you are having.

Comment: @Impurity I updated the post with deeper description of problem